# What exactly causes fallout?

Tags: nuclear-engineering

My former understanding of the emergence of fallout was that the fission products connect with (the dust and) air moisture and rain down.

I have recently learnt that nuclear winter is mainly caused by the mushroom cloud growing so high that it exceeds that part of the atmosphere where rain can arise. Because these particles cannot be washed out by the rain they stay in the air so long and block sun light for years. Against this background I do not understand any more why there is fallout (soon).

If a nuclear bomb explodes several hundred meters / a few kilometers above the ground then the fission products should not touch the ground. They should always be on top of the emerging mushroom cloud (and rise faster because they are hotter) until they reach the maximum height. At that level they should mix with the top of the mushroom cloud. But this top is supposed to be at a height where rain is impossible. So why does the rain contain such a big amount of radioactive particles?

I can imagine that some of the fission products combine with large dust particles which fall down quickly. But in that case you would not "need" rain for the contamination of the ground. But I would expect that this affects only the minority of the fission products.

I understand that radioactive activation by neutrons affects the ground and thus is contained in the lower part of the mushroom cloud where it can rain down. But from what I read the fission products seem to be the main source of radioactivity so this seems to be a rather small effect.

There may also be some convection in the wide top of the mushroom cloud. But in order to have an effect the lower part of it would have to be in the rain area of the atmosphere (I do not know whether that is the case, may depend on the energy of the explosion).

Unfortunately I have not found any information about how a mushroom cloud disappears.

Comment: Not all nuclear explosions cause nuclear winters. Not all material ejected from an explosion reaches the same altitude.